# How to decode json string in LUA?

Tags: c#, json, lua

Currently i am working in C# console application with integration of lua,

My code is given below,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Lua state = new Lua();

        var jsonConcate = @"[{ ""firstName"":""John"" , ""lastName"":""Doe"", ""email"":""NHP@123.COM"" },{ ""firstName"":""Anna"", ""lastName"":""Smith"", ""email"":""ASD@123.COM"" },{ ""firstName"":""Peter"" , ""lastName"":""Jones"", ""email"":""ZXC@123.COM""}]";

        state.DoString(@"
        function ScriptFunc (input)

            local json = require'json'

            local JSON_string = input

            return json.decode(JSON_string) end"
        );

        //            state.DoString(@"function ScriptFunc ( x, y )
        //  return x + y
        //end");

        //state.DoString(@"function concate(inputString) { var sample = JSON.parse(inputString); sample.forEach(function(a) { a.fullname = ['firstName', 'lastName'].map(function(k) { return a[k]; }).join(' ');});");
        var scriptFunc = state["ScriptFunc"] as LuaFunction;

        var res = scriptFunc.Call(jsonConcate);

        // LuaFunction.Call will also return a array of objects, since a Lua function
        // can return multiple values
    }
```

I am getting the error while calling the function like given below,

```
module 'json' not found:

no field package.preload['json']
```

i am not getting any idea about it.

Comment: There are a lot of pure Lua JSON libraries, you can "install" pure Lua library by simply executing its script. For example, take [this script](https://github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/json4lua/blob/master/json.lua), modify its last line from `return json` to `package.preload.json = json` and execute it. After that your `ScriptFunc` will work.

Comment: ok will try this

Comment: @Egor   i got your point but how to use this json.lua file in my code.. i am little confuse about it.. sorry if its a silly question

Comment: You can execute any Lua script with `state.DoString(@"copy file content here with modified last line");` Don't forget to double all double quotes according to C# rules.

Comment: ok got it... actualty i did'nt understand that state.dostring do... thanx

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a json module on your system.  Lua does not come with such a module by default.

Comment: How to install the json module